# Combining results from a loop into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

Working with Python Pandas 0.19.1.

I'm calling a function in loops, which returns a numeric list with length of 4 each time. What's the easiest way of concatenating them into a DataFrame?

I'm doing this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for t in dates:
    result_t = do_some_stuff(t)
    result.append(result_t, ignore_index=True)
```

The problem is that it concatenates along the column instead of by rows.  If `dates` has a length of 250, it gives a single-column df with 1000 rows.  Instead, what I want is a 250 x 4 df.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need append all `DataFrames` to list `result` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
result = []
for t in dates:
    result.append(do_some_stuff(t))

print (pd.concat(result, axis=1))
```